# How to write an equation for a circuit properly?

Tags: linear-algebra

I asked the same question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687150/a-homework-problem-of-finding-currents-in-a-circuit) and the question is now going to be deleted by the Admins there.

First of all I have no knowledge in Physics, I am just studying Linear Algebra.

To find the currents in the following figure we need to establish a system of linear equations.

[here for the circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzGFw.jpg)

This is my try:
$$\begin{cases}
20I_{1}+10I_{2} & =-5\\
10I_{2}-10(I_1 -I_2) & =-10
\end{cases}$$

In fact I followed the (Physics) rules from the book Elementary linear algebra by Anton and Rorres on [page 87](https://geometria.math.bme.hu/sites/geometria.math.bme.hu/files/users/csgeza/howard-anton-chris-rorres-elementary-linear-algebra-applications-version-11th-edition.pdf). However a person from the Physics site suggested that I was wrong. And the system should be

$$\begin{cases}
20I_{1}+10I_{2} & =5\\
10I_{2}-10(I_1 -I_2) & =-10
\end{cases}$$

My question: Since this is purely to apply some accepted principles in Physics and I followed the rules in a Math book, I got confused a whole day. Could someone confirm what should it be?

Comment: We are fortunate to have [electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) stackoverflow. If your question is about setting up the equation, then you need to ask it there.

Comment: I check it using KCL and KVL.  You got the right equations, and the person from the Physics site gave you the wrong equations.

Comment: Yes, but how about people who are teaching linear algebra? Could anyone have a comment? I am sure a site like "electrical engineering stackoverflow" would again delete my question.

Comment: @Hosam Hajjir Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a potential walk along the upper loop, clockwise beginning at the upper left corner.

First we have a resistor, but the current is set to have a positive flow to the left, so the potential *increases* instead of decreases with $20\ \Omega \cdot I_1$. Then comes the battery giving a potential *increase* with $5\ \mathrm{V}$. On the way back to the left through the middle resistor we again get a potential *increase* of $10\ \Omega \cdot I_2$ since we move against the current. Now, the total potential change along a loop should vanish. Thus we get the equation
$$
20\ \Omega \cdot I_1 + 5\ \mathrm{V} + 10\ \Omega \cdot I_2 = 0
$$
i.e.
$$
20\ \Omega \cdot I_1 + 10\ \Omega \cdot I_2 = -5\ \mathrm{V}.
$$

A trap here is that the currents $I_1$ and $I_2$ will actually be negative. This might confuse people, even those who know the laws of electricity very well.

Comment: Thank so much. I don't have a Physics background. The way I go for any loop is that: I will go out from the positive sign of a battery along the loop, if I encounter a current going in the opposite direction then I add its volume to the volume of the battery, if it goes in the same direction I subtract it. The whole sum is always set to be zero.